# Is there any way to pass media key events back to Windows from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome 73 added media key support for playing videos in the browser (e.g. YouTube). I'm trying to make a chrome extension that let's you use media keys for both Chrome and system media (like normal control for Spotify or media players). I can intercept the media key event in Chrome using the MediaSession API, but have no idea if it is possible to also 'free' the media key event and let it propagate to the next system media process. Does anyone even know it if possible/how I could do it?

This is how I am currently capturing the media key events ('play', 'pause', 'nexttrack' and 'previoustrack'):

```
window.onload = function() {

    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() {
      console.log('play media key pressed');
      playMedia(document);
    });

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, which is rather weird - try asking in the [API repo](https://github.com/WICG/mediasession). A workaround would be to write a separate utility that would send the media key(s) into OS event queue, and invoke it from your extension via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using the method below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to get JS to play system media, so to get around this I sent a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) from the content scripts to the background process, which then sent a message to every tab, telling them to stop their respective videos (pause it and remove the source) to let the user play system media, and then restart the videos.